# Select only few columns in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query

```
 var xyz = from a in prod.Categories
                           where a.CatName.EndsWith("A")
                           select a;
```

However all the columns are returned in this case. How do i rewrite query so that only few columns are returned like a.CatName, a.CatID, a.CatQty and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var xyz = from a in prod.Categories
                           where a.CatName.EndsWith("A")
                           select new { CatName=a.CatName, CatID=a.CatID, CatQty = a.CatQty};
```

Comment: CatName=a.CatName is redundant, can just use 

select new { a.CatName, a.CatID, ... etc};

Answer (score 4):

```
 var xyz = from a in prod.Categories
                           where a.CatName.EndsWith("A")
                           select new { a.CatID,a.CatQty } ;
```