# How to Select subset of columns from SingleOrDefault LINQ query in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

How can I select subset of all columns while using `SingleOrDefault` query? For example, following LINQ expression

```
var personid = ctx.persons.SingleOrDefault(p => p.login == currentLogin)?.personid;
```

will compile into `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ...` type of query. I would like to `Select()` only the columns I am interested in, e.g. statement producing `SELECT TOP 1 personid, myColumn FROM ...` under-hood.

Please note, that the question cannot possibly be duplicate of [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466465/select-only-few-columns-in-linq-query). I am interested in context of `Single`/`SingleOrDefault` not generic solution for LINQ. Chaining `.SingleOrDefault()` with `.Select()` is *not possible* for apparent reasons: `Single<T>`returns single object of type `T` (or throws) which clearly does not implement `IEnumerable<T>` and cannot be `Select()`ed upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var personid = ctx.persons
    .Where(p => p.login == currentLogin)
    .Select(p => new {Prop = p.Column, personid = p.id})
    .SingleOrDefault()?.personid;
```

Would probably work.

Comment: Interesting idea to `Where` followed by empty `SingleOrDefault`, weirdly enough it does compile into two `SELECT` statements. But I guess it is the closest one can get with EF.

Comment: The more research I do on the topic the more I am convinced this workaround is THE (only) answer. I would not suggest using it unless there are really big blobs you dont want to be sent (on lesser scale, it was the original reason for asking the question), but it does not make it any less correct.

Comment: If you do not want to retrieve everything from the database, you need a `Select` before the `SingleOrDefault`. To be able to filter the result by properties which are not selected, you need a `Where` before the `Select`.