# Is there a way to include certain fields of a class in linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My class structure is as follows. I'm trying to include the User field for the Order result. But I don't want to get the Orders property of the User class.

```
public class Order{
   public int OrderId { get; set; }
   public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User{
   public int UserId {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string SurName {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

I wrote this code.

```
var orders = context.Set<Order>()
                    .Include(t => new { Name = t.User.Name, Surname = t.User.SurName })
                    .ToList();
```

But I get an error that

> The expression 'new <>f__AnonymousType20`2(Name = (t As Order).User.Name, Surname = (t As Order).User.SurName)' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393."](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.%22)

Comment: Use [`.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0) instead of `.Include()` ?

Comment: But wouldn't that slow down my query anyway?

Comment: This appears to be LINQ to Entities for Entity Framework: if it is please tag correctly. If it isn't tag with the LINQ provider you are using.

Comment: @ezgigokdemir `.Select()` will make the query faster. You're trying to use `Include` as if it was `Select` already. LINQ isn't magic, nor a replacement for SQL. A LINQ query is translated to a SQL `SELECT` query. When you don't use an explicit` Select` you're effectively executing `SELECT *`, loading all fields in a row even if you only need 1 of them. By using a `.Select()` to specify a few fields only, you generate a `SELECT` that only loads those fields.

Comment: "But wouldn't that slow down my query anyway?" - the fact that you're `.Include(t t=>t.User)` means, "also look there at that Users table". It doesn't mean that the whole User will be fetched. On the database level, it means a join from Orders to Users. Yes, it may slow down the query a little. However, it does not mean that the whole User and all its columns will be fetched. If you ran a full .ToList, then indeed, by default whole Order and whole User are fetched, but if you add `.Select` and choose only some fields/props of Order and some of User, then the rest will be omitted if possible.

Comment: @ezgigokdemir `Include` doesn't include related data. If your `Select` requires data from a related entity, EF Core will generate the necessary `SELECT` query. If a JOIN is needed, EF Core will use it, even if there's no `Include`. `Include()`, as the docs clearly explain, is used to force eager loading - loading related entities even if they aren't mentioned in the `Select` caluse

Comment: @quetzalcoatl  `context.Set<Order>()` is a smell too, and probably a performance issue. It's a smell because it's not needed, unless you somehow tried to create a "generic repository", even though DbContext is already generic. It's a performance issue because before EF Core 6, EF Core would cache the metadata for `DbSet<T>` properties but not for `Set<T>()`. DbContext is a Unit-of-Work for a specific use case, so you almost always know what DbSets are involved. DbSet is the repository class.

Comment: In your case, the query you need is `var users=context.Orders.Select(o=>new {o.User.Name,o.User.Surname}).ToList()`, eg `context.Orders.Where(o=>o.Date>DateTime.Today).Select(0=>...)`

Comment: I included the User property and then used select. I used ToList() after selecting the query. The result came faster. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you have something like `Select(x => new ...` you don't need `Include`. @quetzalcoatl's comment isn't correct and based on a far too common misconception. Projection and `Include` are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select only few columns in LINQ query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466465/select-only-few-columns-in-linq-query)

Comment: @GertArnold Please read carefully. I might have been a bit unclear,but nowhere I did write that one has to use Include for making a Projection. I said what 'include' could be thougth of, and that '.select' will limit what the query fetches, **even if `Include` was included in the query**.  And it unsurprisingly does so despite being 'mutually exclusive' (which it is not - no exceptions when using both,right?). I was providing a simplistic view and had no intention of diving into tracked/detached/lazy/eager/batching/entities/projections, which are needed to properly discuss the topic in full

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to include the User field for the Order result.

So you want to query a sequence of Orders, every Order with several properties of the User of this Order.

```
var orders = dbContext.Orders
    .Where(order => ...)        // if you don't want all Orders
    .Select(order => new
    {
        // Select only the Order properties that you plan to use
        Id = order.Id,
        Total = order.Total,
        ...

        // The User of this Order
        User = new
        {
            // Select only the User properties that you plan to use
            Id = order.User.Id,
            Name = order.User.Name,
            ...
        },
    });
```

I use anonymous type here. If you need to return the fetched data from a procedure you need to put the data in a predefined class.

Some versions of entity framework won't support using the virtual properties. In that case you'll have to do the (Group-)Join yourself. If you start at the "one" side in a one-to-many relation, do a GroupJoin; if you start at the "many" side, a standard join will suffice. Use the overload that has a parameter `resultSelector` to precisely request what you want.

```
var orders = dbContext.Orders
    .Where(order => ...)
    .Join(dbContext.Users,

    order => order.UserId,   // from every Order take the foreign key to the user
    user => user.UserId,     // from every User take the primary key

    // Parameter resultSelector: get every Order with its one and only user
    // to make one new
    (order, userOfThisOrder) => new
    {
        Id = order.Id,
        TotalPrice = order.TotalPrice,

        User = new
        {
           Id = userOfThisOrder.UserId,
           Name = userOfThisOrder.Name,
           ...
        },
    });
```

### Why not use include?

`Include` will fetch the complete row of the table, inclusive the properties that you won't use, or properties of which you already know the value.

Suppose you have a School database with Schools and Students, and a one-to-many relation with a foreign key: every School has zero or more Students, every Student attends exactly one School, namely the School that the foreign key `SchoolId` refers to.

Now if you fetch School [10], and use `Include` to fetch all its 2000 Students, then you'll fetch the foreign key SchoolId once for every fetched Student. You already know that this foreign key will have a value 10. You will be transferring this value  over 2000 times. What a waste of processing power.

Another reason not to fetch complete rows, and not use Include is the following. The DbContext holds a ChangeTracker. When you fetch a complete row, the data is stored in the ChangeTracker, together with a Clone. You get the reference to the Original. Whenever you change values of properties of the retrieved data, you change the values in the Original. If you update the changed data using `SaveChanges`, then the original is compared by value with the clone in the ChangeTracker. Only the changed properties will be sent to the database.

So if you fetch School [10] with all its 2000 Students, and you don't plan to update the fetched data, then fetching the complete rows will fetch one School and 2000 Students. Every fetched item will be copied. And if you later fetch Student [42] to change his Address, and call SaveChanges, all fetched 2000 Students will be compared with their Clones, value by value. What a waste of processing power, if you didn't plan to update any of these 2000 Students.

> When using entity framework always use Select and select only the properties that you actually plan to use. Only fetch complete rows, only use Include, if you plan to update the fetched data.